# How to edit internal storage Json file from code

Tags: android, json

I'm working on an android app.
the layout is set according to a Json file I hold in the internal storage.
the Json file should be changed from an online Url so the app won't need to be updated all the time.
I wrote inside an AsyncTask a code that gets the Json file from the web (http://myjson.com) and the string is ok.
now I am trying to update my internal storage file to the one i got from web but it is not changed. 
every thing compiles, the app is running. but the json file is not updated.

this is what i tried:
(JsonData is the string from web, mainactivity is an instance of my app's main activity)

```
final File JsonFile = new File(mainActivity.getFilesDir() + "/DefaultJson.json");
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(JsonFile);
file.write(JsonData);
file.flush();
file.close();
```

this code gave the same result:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = mainActivity.openFileOutput("DefaultJson.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fOut.write(JsonData.getBytes());
fOut.close();
```

note that this was written inside doInBackground()

Comment: `this code gave the save result:`. You mean `the same` ? You are not showing us how you read the file or how you check if it is there.

Comment: @greenapps why would it matter how i read the file? right now i am not checking if it is there. maybe the problem is the file's path? currently it is right under the main folder.

Comment: Main folder? If you want help you better show how you read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the save method did work, i was just looking at the wrong file and that is why i did not see a change in its content.
i don't know where it is being saved, but once i managed to read it from code and not manually it turned out the file did change. 
the file i manually copied to the app was not the same file the program treated.